# How set Batch variable to be used into other Batch commands into Jenkins pipeline file

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When trying to use a variable inside another BATCH command, the result of %DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR% is empty.

```
bat "set DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR=docker inspect container1 -f {{.NetworkSettings.Gateway}}"
bat "docker run -d --name container2 -p 8084:8084 container-test:latest --container1-uri=http://%DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR%:4444"
```

How can I set a variable to be used in a Jenkins pipeline file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either combine both these bat commands into one, like this:

```
bat """
   set DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR=docker inspect container1 -f {{.NetworkSettings.Gateway}}
   docker run -d --name container2 -p 8084:8084 container-test:latest --container1-uri=http://%DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR%:4444
"""
```

OR get the output of first command and save it as env var in script and use string interpolation in second command, like this:

```
env.DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR = bat returnStdout:true, script: "docker inspect container1 -f {{.NetworkSettings.Gateway}}"

// Trim the trailing newline
env.DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR = env.DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR.trim()

bat "docker run -d --name container2 -p 8084:8084 container-test:latest --container1-uri=http://${env.DOCKER_GATEWAY_ADDR}:4444"
```